# Show that $V \setminus U$ is never a subspace of $V$ given $U \leq V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having problems with the following problem:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $U \leq V$. Show that $V \setminus U$ is
>   never a subspace of $V$.

I'm not sure how to start out with showing that  $V \setminus U$ is not a subspace of $V$. Should I start out with using the general steps with determining if the subset $V \setminus U$ is a subspace of $V$? Or should I give some type of counter example?

Comment: Well, if $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then does $0$ belong to $V \setminus U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** is the zero vector in $V\setminus U$?

By the way, note that you are asked to prove that it is **never** a subspace of $V$. So a specific example will not help here.